# Laravel Routing for SEO path / title of a table

Tags: laravel, routes, seo, laravel-routing

i need to ask solution of my problem

usually people make url path like mylaravelsite/products/{id}
ex. mylaravelsite/products/1

i'm build a website but i need to create url path like mylaravelsite/products/{title}
example:
mylaravelsite/products/name-of-product

after doing **The Alpha**  solution and thats works :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it. It doesn't matter if you want to use a parameter as `slug/string` instead of an `id/numeric`. Just declare the route the same way you would have declared for a numeric `id` parameter. For example, you may declare a route like this:

```
Route::get(
    '/products/{title}',
    array('uses' => 'ProductController@show', 'as' => 'product.show')
);
```

Then, the `URL` for this route could be `http://yourdomain.com/products/name-of-product`.

The reason people use an `id` because, most often people use an `auto-incremented`  numeric `id` a `primary key` in their database and it's a good idea to use something like that which would be unique. You just make sure that your products are unique as well and insert them as slug in your database using:

```
$product->title = Str::slug(Input::get('product_title'));
```

Also, you may use a where condition in your route to make sure that the product name supplied to the route is an string using something like this:

```
Route::get(
    '/products/{title}',
    array('uses' => 'ProductController@show', 'as' => 'product.show')
)->where('title', '[A-Za-z-]+');
```

This is a macro I've used for same reason (From Slug to Title):

```
Str::macro('toTitle', function($str){
    return ucwords(str_replace('-', ' ', $str));
});
```

You may use a normal helper function as well and maybe you may use `preg_replace` if needed.

Comment: if i insert my title as slug in my database
how i can print out it with normal title (without slug)

Comment: It's very simple, just replace the `-_`.

Comment: i get some error like findRoute , dispatch, match etc
i will edit and post it again

Comment: sorry that's my fault it's because $ on Route::get('/news/{$title}') haha btw thanks thats works :)